# Hot to check if an array of type FTPFile for a string?

Tags: java, arrays, ftp

I am retrieving a list of files from a particular location on an FTP server and then i need to check if a particular filename is in it. if the file dosent exist, i want to provide an alternate filename to check.

```
FTPFile[] ftpFiles = ftp.listFiles(pdfBean.getFileLocation());
String fileName = pdfBean.getFileName().tostring();
```

How can i check if filename exists in ftpFiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run in loop on `ftpFiles`:

```
String fileName = pdfBean.getFileName().tostring();   

private boolean isFtpFileExist(String fileName){
for(FTPFile file : ftpFiles ){

       if (file.getType() == FTPFile.FILE_TYPE) {
            // ....
          if(file.getName().equals(fileName)){
             return true;
          }
        }

    }

 return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
FTPFile primary;
FTPFile secondary;
String pFileName; // primary file
String sFileName; // secondary file name
// set those name strings...
for(int i = 0; i < ftpFiles.length; ++i) {
   if(ftpFiles[i].getName() == pFileName)
      primary = ftpFiles[i];
   else if(ftpFiles[i].getName() == sFileName)
      secondary = ftpFiles[i];
}
```

Since you have a standard array, you'll need to search it yourself.